# What prompts installation of security updates for Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: windows-10, flash-player

Today Windows 10 on my work computer installed an update called *Security Update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1909 for x64-based systems (KB4537759)* through Windows Update.

The Windows update log reveals that multiple security updates for Adobe Flash Player have been installed since the PC has been set up, for example in June and September of 2019.

To the best of my knowledge, Adobe Flash Player hasn't been manually installed on this PC since its setup about a year ago, and none of the browsers currently installed list it as an installed add-on.

Is the installation of these security updates prompted by Flash Player's presence somewhere, or is it simply installed on every Windows PC as a precaution?

Comment: You may want to make sure that Flash is disabled in Edge, and also in IE11 if you have that installed, if you have concerns about its security. In Chrome 76 and later, Flash Player is turned off by default, but you may need to check.

Comment: Flash updates were included with Edge when Windows 10 came out (or shortly after) and Windows Updates look after updated Flash now. I got the same updates here on several machines.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I completely forgot that Edge is a thing - and there it is! In Edge, *Settings, Advanced, Adoble Flash* was toggled *on*. So the update was definitely justified.

Comment: @waldrumpus I would think that Flash should still be updated even if it isn't turned on. Let me have a look in my update history.... ah, yes, the Flash updates do still happen with Flash disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash player is present in the Edge browser, at the time of writing.

It will still receive updates through Microsoft/Windows Update even if it is disabled in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

By KB4537759 you may refer to the
[Security Update for Adobe Flash Player: February 11, 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537759/security-update-for-adobe-flash-player).

It is of importance to know how these updates are introduced and
whether you are prompted for them by some program.

If the installing program is the Adobe updater, then this is just an over-jealous
installation whose origin is some Adobe product that you have installed.

If the installing program is Windows Update, it may just be an over-cautious update
caused by Windows badly analyzing the presence of some other installed Adobe
product.

However, a possible complication exists because there are computer viruses and trojans
that emulate the Adobe updater, even to the point where a fake Adobe updater
is really updating Adobe Flash. So, just in case you have a virus masquerading as
the Adobe updater, you should do some deep scans of the computer by some
well-known anti-virus products.

If no virus infection is found, then you may ignore these useless Adobe updates.

For more information, see:

- [Fake Adobe update really *does* update Flash (while also installing cryptominer)](https://www.tripwire.com/state-of-security/featured/fake-adobe-update-cryptominer/)
- [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)